# Recovering Red Hat 6.4

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linker, redhat

I was trying to down-version glib library installed on my Red Hat 6.4 server. First, I uninstalled it using-

```
rpm -e --nodeps glib
```

After that I am unable to execute terminal commands (e.g. ls, cd). Now, I want to recover my system. How can do that? Thanks.

[I have Red Hat 6.4 iso. I tried to see any option given while booting from it. But unable to find.]

Comment: This question may be more suited for http://serverfault.com/

Comment: Erasing glibc should be the last thing an admin should do that to directly with `rpm` command. At-least next time consider using `yum upgrade`, if its required to switch to a different version of glibc. Did you try booting into rescue mode and manually install glibc rpm ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Boot the machine to rescue mode.
2. Mount the CD/DVD to some temp directory
   mkdir temp

   mount /dev/hdc temp
3. Check the output of the to find any missing files and dependencies.
   rpm -Va
4. Now find the rpm location on the CD/DVD/ISO.
5. Install the RPM manually.

   rpm -ivh --force --noscripts --root=/mnt/sysimage /path/to/glibc.rpm /path/to/other/missing.rpm
6. Reboot the system and run `rpm -Va` again